# How to put a variable under one function as an argument under another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, arguments

I want to use the input provided by the user under one function as the argument under another. Example:

```
def f(value):
    age = raw_input('>')
    return
def hello(age):
    print "You are %d years old" %age
    return

f(0)
hello(age)
```

When I do so, I get the error that the variable age is not defined. How to counteract this.

Comment: always remember that variables inside the functions have a local scope !

Answer (score 1):

You need to return age from your function `f` and use that value in `hello()`:

```
def f():
    age = raw_input('>')
    return age

def hello():
    return  "You are {} years old".format(f())

print hello()
```

You should have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) on functions

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the user input function in the hello function:

```
def f():
  age = raw_input('>')
  return age

def hello(age):
  print "You are %d years old" % (age)
  return age

hello(f())
```